# Shimano Front derailleur

Tags: derailleur, front

I am rebuilding a Trek 2005 model 6500 and my spec. sheet for the bike says it has a Shimano Alivio front derailleur.  Where do I find the model no. that should be stamped on the part? I don't see it anywhere on the part.  This is a 3 x 8 speed setup.

Thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 4):

You might have a hard time finding the exact same part that was originally on the bike. However, front derailleur is a pretty standard piece of kit and you can replace it with compatible.

Things you need to look for when buying front mech:

- Road and MTB FDs are different
- Shimano and SRAM FDs work with the others shifters (which is different for RDs)
- Seatpost clamp diameter - size of the tube the mech is clamping around (Shimano FDs often come with shims but SRAM FDs do not)
- If the mech is top pull or bottom pull: the cable comes from above the derailleur (top pull) or below (bottom pull). Dual pull derailleurs work either way.
- There are 3 clamp positions: high clamp sits above the mechanism, low clamp is at the same level of the mechanism and e type is on a frame which sits between the bottom bracket and the crankset.
- Make sure the new mech is 8 speed. 9 speed-mech won't work with 8 speed chain, as the chain widths are different.

Comment: I believe from images I've seen that the 2005 Trek 6500 had a top pull, low clamp FD.

Comment: For what its worth, a lower end FD marketed for a 3x9 setup will probably work with a 3x8 fine with a 8 speed chain (you can run a 9 speed chain on an 8 speed system if you want -  its typically fine as well) since the cage probably wasn't narrowed (much) at this spec level. Also, if you have things like sram attack, you can switch between sram and shimano to a further extent (though alivio/acera/altus level parts for 3x8 are cheap enough that you're not going to save any money).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on Shimano's site. They list two types of Alivio - 8-speed and 9-speed - so presumably the page you're after is the 8-speed kit: 
http://cycle.shimano-eu.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/nl/index/components/mountain/Alivio.html

The three different options here appear to be the FD-M410E, FD-M412 and FD-M413. There are photos of all three (looks like the main difference is the position of the clamp), so you should be able to work out what you have right now.